# UnderScore Dynamic Filter during onchange event

Tags: javascript, html, underscore.js, onchange

While  trying  to filter  an object by passing a parameter during **onchange** event, Am getting an empty array as a result.

While Trying hard-coding those key and value it returns an object and its working fine,In this case it will always return an array which has **Ram**  as value

```js
var empDetails = [{
    name: "Raju",
    id: 123
  },
  {
    name: "Ram",
    id: 456
  }, {
    name: "Anand",
    id: 789
  }, {
    name: "Venkat",
    id: 987
  }
];
function onFilter(columnName) {
  var columnValue = document.getElementById(columnName).value;
  empDetails = _.filter(empDetails, {
    "name": "Ram"
  });
  console.log(empDetails);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="name" type="text" onchange="onFilter('name')">
```

But in this following case its returning an empty array

```js
var empDetails = [{
    name: "Raju",
    id: 123
  },
  {
    name: "Ram",
    id: 456
  }, {
    name: "Anand",
    id: 789
  }, {
    name: "Venkat",
    id: 987
  }
];
function onFilter(columnName) {
console.log(columnName);
  var columnValue = document.getElementById(columnName).value;
  console.log(columnValue);
  empDetails = _.filter(empDetails, {
    columnName: columnValue
  });
  console.log(empDetails);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="name" type="text" onchange="onFilter('name')">
```

Comment: What is the filter attempting to filter exactly? The second argument of filter should be a function returning a `boolean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You filter for the key `"columnName"` and not `"name"`, as you expected.

This solution will work for you, but is without underscore.js

```js
var empDetails = [{
    name: "Raju",
    id: 123
  }, {
    name: "Ram",
    id: 456
  }, {
    name: "Anand",
    id: 789
  }, {
    name: "Venkat",
    id: 987
  }
];
function onFilter(columnName) {
  console.log(columnName);
  var columnValue = document.getElementById(columnName).value;
  console.log(columnValue);
  var filteredEmpDetails = empDetails.filter(function (el) {
    return el[columnName] === columnValue;
  });
  console.log(filteredEmpDetails);
}
```

```html
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="name" type="text" onchange="onFilter('name')">
```

And you probably should use an internal variable `filteredEmpDetails` to be able to use the `onFilter`-function more than once.

Comment: This Works only for the first time,But when u try to hit second time its  returning empty array

Comment: I already changed the code, you used internally also `empDetails` and destroyed your original Array

Answer (score 0):

**Filter**

**`_.filter(list, predicate, [context])`**

*Looks through each value in the list, returning an array of all the values that pass a truth test (predicate).*

---

You had a few issues with your code.

- First up, the second argument of `_.filter` should be a function
  returning a `bool` dictating weather the item should be filtered out
  or not.
- Secondly, you were defining `empDetails` **outside** of your
  `onFilter` function, it should be defined **inside** so each
  execution of `onFilter` does not depend on one `empDetails` variable.

The code below should solve your issues:

```js
function onFilter(columnName) {
    var empDetails = [
     {
         name: "Raju",
      id: 123
     },
     {
      name: "Ram",
      id: 456
     },
     {
      name: "Anand",
      id: 789
     },
     {
      name: "Venkat",
      id: 987
     }
    ];
 console.log(columnName);
 var columnValue = document.getElementById(columnName).value;
 console.log(columnValue);
 empDetails = _.filter(empDetails, val => val[columnName] == columnValue);
 console.log(empDetails);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-sm" id="name" type="text" onchange="onFilter('name')">
```

Comment: This Works only for the first time,But when u try to hit second time its  returning empty array

Comment: I think its not working can u please check it, I am not getting console.log